# Recording audio output from phone with Audacity and AUX cable

Tags: audio-recording, audacity, noise

I am trying to record the phone output audio using AUX cable connected to my PC mic jack.
The recorded raw file is filled with a noise.
Does anyone know how could I eliminate that noise?

I am using audacity/arecord (for command line).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem was high input level.

Comment: Please post the above comment as an answer to your own question. You are permitted to click the gray check mark beside your answer to mark it as accepted starting 48 hours after when you posted the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was high input level, after I lowered it from: **System Settings** > **Sound** > **Input** > (Set Input Volume to **Unamplified**), the noise was gone.
See the noise before and after:[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUPDA.png)